# Manipulate an element that is conditionally rendered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if

I'm fixing a bug on some legacy Angular 1.5 code.

I have a template like this

```
<div id="container" ng-if="ctrl.show_container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I need to manipulate the `div#child`. I'm using $element.find() to get the child div. Unfortunately, it seems that code runs before the template/DOM has finished rendering -- due to the conditional rendering on the container, it doesn't find anything. If I remove the `ng-if`, it's able to find the element as expected.

Is there any way I can execute my DOM manipulation until after all the conditional rendering is done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', functionToManipulateDom)
```

Answer (score 0):

If simple case you just do:

```
ctrl.show_container = true;
$timeout(() => $element.find(...))
```

If that is not enough you'd better add some directive on that `#child` element.